# Spree how to use Hooks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

According to http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/theming.html#hooks you should be able to use spree hooks using my_theme_hooks.rb but how? Do I need to extend a class and where can I check which hooks are used in the default theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following this http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/boot_modes.html I found the difference

Comment: Sounds like a 0.60.x feature, so the link would be: http://guides.spreecommerce.com/legacy/0-60-x/customization.html#hooks now. If anyone else is searching for this.